# Why does my iphone 6s not wake up for a phone call?

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep-wake, charging

Sometimes when unplugging my iPhone 6s from the charger, the screen stays black without waking up. I have checked and determined that did charge the battery so I know it had a good connection. If I get a phone call (while plugged in or after unplugging) sometimes I can hear the ring tone but the screen is still black and I cannot see to swipe the answer button. I have to hit the home button to make the screen come alive. This happens intermittently and only while plugged in or just after. Anyone else have this experience?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that I've ever gotten a call on my iPhone 6s while it was charging before, but I can say that some of the little things about the iPhone 6s are buggy, like how some system sounds don't always play.

All that I could recommend is to update to iOS 9.1, as my iPhone 6s is noticeably less buggy on 9.1 than it was on any earlier iOS 9 release.